# Instantiate random different gameObjects in specific spaces?

Tags: unity, c#

I need to instantiate different gameObjects of different shapes and sizes on top of the left third and the right third of a table, and all this objects need to be random every time the scene loads. I have a library of around 80 GO but the most I'll instantiate, for now, is 30. All the instantiated GO have to be different, that means no duplicates.

I thought that maybe I could create 30 empty gameObjects on the table, where I want to instantiate them in random, but I'm not sure if this is the most intelligent way to do it. Is there any other way?

Also, since I have a library of GO so large, would it be possible to load the folder in the script instead of defining a list and populating it in the editor?

I'm a bit new at coding for Unity, but I'm an experienced programmer.

Comment: It sounds like you have a workable solution to this problem. How have you tried implementing it so far? Did you run into a particular snag we can help you with? And presumably you searched for [existing documented workflows for referencing large collections of assets](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1417421/how-to-load-all-my-sprites-in-my-folder-and-put-th.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing the instantiation itself:

- You could place the 30 empty gameobject as you wish in the level and then **spawn objects as children of those empty gameobjects**. Signature: `public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);`
- You can place the 30 empty gameobjects, and **just use their transform** when spawning your objects (this way doesn't require any kind of hierarchy). Signature: `public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);`
- (You could also programmatically compute the transform of each object, that's a valid option as well)

When it comes to **scanning a given path to find all assets**, take a look at the **`AssetDatabase.FindAssets`** helper: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.FindAssets.html
(You can even filter with specifics asset labels!)

To avoid copying the output list of FindAssets to shuffle it, you can **generate a list of randomized indexes using Linq**, and then simplify iterate on this index list:

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    List<int> indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).OrderBy((item)=> rnd.Next()).ToList();
```

Cheers!